# Objects disappearing with fading submenu code - jQuery bug?

Tags: jquery, visibility, mouseover, submenu

I am building a site, and have a menu which has dropdowns. Due to the nature of the design, I currently detect when the mouse is over menu item; and show the associated submenu.

```
                                <div class="menu-responsibility menu-item">
                                            <a class="menu-click" href="<?php echo ($baseURL);?>responsibility" title="Responsibility" ></a>

                                                            <div class="sub-responsibility">
                                                                <ul class="sub-list">
                                                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>responsibility/social" title="Social Responsibility">Social</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>responsibility/environmental" title="Environmental Responsibility">Environmental</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>responsibility/philanthropy" title="Philanthropy">Philanthropy</a></li>
                                                                </ul>      
                                                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Here is the JS I've written:

```
        /* NOTE: Visibility was added due to display objects being clickable with 0 opacity. */
$(".menu-click").hover(function () {
$(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
$(this).parent().css('visibility', 'visible');
$(this).parent().fadeTo("fast", 1);
}, function () {
if ($(this).parent().is(':hover')) {
//alert ("hovering");
} else {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo("fast", 0);
}
});

$(".menu-click").parent().mouseleave(function () {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
    // this function will called after the opacity animation has completed
    $(this).delay(500).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
});
    /*End Sub-Menu Function */
```

This worked fine when just fading; but when the opacity was 0 and the elements were still visible, they could be clicked (just not seen), and this was unacceptable.

The Bug:
*Sometimes*, completely randomly, some of the hover state's of the menu (and adjoined submenu) disappear. They are no longer there, and cannot be highlighted. This will randomly happen to one of the menu items if you run your mouse across them quickly. Firebug shows the following when the "Results" menu item is doing this. It can no longer be highlighted.

```
<div class="menu-home menu-item">
<div class="menu-services menu-item" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
<div class="menu-results menu-item" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<div class="menu-clients menu-item" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
<div class="menu-about menu-item" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<div class="menu-responsibility menu-item" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<div class="menu-contact menu-item">
```

Very strange bug, hopefully you guys can help! My Dev site is available and will probably help: http://www.kipdo.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to how you use the .parent() function.

I would suggest you rather use JQuery's .hide() and .show() functions instead of altering the inline CSS.
Another suggestion would be to use the parent  tag to maintain the hover/hide/show so that you do not have to deal with the parents of any links in your menu, within the .